# c - initialization makes integer from pointer

Tags: c

I am trying get number ASCII for letter in char variable.  My code so far is:

```
 int main (int argc,char* argv[]) {
    char c="A"; //here error
    char b="'"; //here error
    char d="z"; //and here error
    printf("%d\n %d\n %d\n",c,b,d); 
}
```

But I get the following errors:

> ```
> analizer.c: In function ‘main’:
> analizer.c:13:8: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
> analizer.c:14:8: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
> analizer.c:15:8: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
> ```

Comment: char c="A"; is invalid, use char c='A';

Comment: compiler is not rude, nothing personal, its telling you what the issues are.

Comment: What is rude about that?

Comment: just some morning joke :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"A"` is a *string literal* (an array of characters). `'A'` is a *character constant* (an integer). What you want should be latter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc,char* argv[]) {
    char c='A';
    char b='\''; // use escape sequence
    char d='z';
    printf("%d\n %d\n %d\n",c,b,d); 
}
```

The compiler will allow you to extract elements of the arrays (string literals) like below, but using character constants should be better in this case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc,char* argv[]) {
    char c="A"[0]; // a typical way to deal with arrays
    char b=*"'"; // dereferencing of a pointer converted from an array
    char d=0["z"]; // a tricky way: this is equivalent to *((0) + ("z"))
    printf("%d\n %d\n %d\n",c,b,d); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you point to a string literal when you do this (which is invalid):

```
char c="A";
```

You need to write a single char to the variables:

```
char c='A';
char b='\'';
char b='z';
```

Answer (score 1):

In `C` strings are just an array of characters which terminate with a `\0`. So if you want to use only one character, declare a `char` variable and use the character `single` quote. If you want to use a string, declare `char` array and use `double`quote as

```
char a='A' //  just one character
char b[20]="Some_Text"// multiple characters(a string)
```

In the first case, `a` contains the integer value of 'A' but in the second, `b` contains the base address of the string it points to. Each character in array `b[]` must be accessed with indexes as `b[0]` `b[1]` etc.

You can use strings to represent single characters as

```
char a[]="A" // a string of size 1
```

and then you can print it's integer equivalent as

```
printf("%d",a[0]); //0th element of the string
```

## or

use the single quote method as described in other answers.

Comment: `char a[1]="A"` is unusual and misleading. It is equivalent, for example, to `char a[1]="ABCDE"`; the declared array of one element is initialized with the necessary number of subsequent characters from the character string literal, more specifically with the first character, the 'A'. The remaining characters in the literal are ignored. `a` will not be 0 terminated. It would be better to write `char a[2]="A"`, and best to write `char a[]="A"`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider You are absolutely correct. I just wanted to make things simpler for the OP. You are welcome to edit my answer if you find it misleading.